# When plotting a raster, how to change the maximum and minimum values of the legend?

Tags: r, raster, terra

[image]

This is a mean annual temperature map in Celsius/10. It was downloaded from https://envicloud.wsl.ch/#/?prefix=chelsa%2Fchelsa_V1.

I tried this:

```
min_val <- -15000
max_val <- 0

plot(r, col = rev(terrain.colors(10)), at = seq(min_val, max_val, length.out = 11))
```

But it only creates break points. The map looks the same, the only difference is that it creates 9 break points in the legend so I don't have a gradient in color in the legend anymore.

This doesn't work either:

```
plot(r, range=c(-20000, 0))
```

It gives a blank plot.

Comment: Try the `breaks` argument instead of `at` for plotting using the {raster} package e.g. `plot(r, col = rev(terrain.colors(10)), breaks = seq(min_val, max_val, length.out = 11))`